# Can not resolved symbol, Groovy + IntelliJIDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy

I've tried to import defaultActor in my project but I got an error about `groovyx` and `DefaultActor`: *can not resolve symbol*.

Any idea why I got this error?

```
import groovyx.gpars.actor.DefaultActor
import loggers.Logger


class Agent extends DefaultActor {....}
```

> IDEA 15, JDK 1.8.0.65, Groovy

Comment: Which version of groovy are you using?

Comment: groovy 2.4.5 @jalopaba

Comment: GPars is included in groovy 2.4.5. Which symbol is not resolved?

Comment: Thanks it solved, I added GPars and it works. :) @jalopaba